# Entity Framework data compression

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, compression

I have a WCF Windows service that provides data to 250+ PDAs via compressed datasets and was looking to redevelop both the service and the mobile application to use Entity Framework 4.x models.

In order to keep performance acceptable when sending/receiving data on the PDA I need to keep the data size as small as possible and was wondering if its possible to compress a IEnumerable from the WCF windows service?

From previous experience with the datasets I got a 80%+/- compression rate and even decompressing the data on the PDA achieved an overal 50% performance importment so retaining similar levels of performance is critical.

EDIT:
Could I use a binary serializer and then compress the stream?  [As shown here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14491/Serialize-and-Deserialize-IEnumerable-Objects)

Comment: Why don't you use the GZip compression supported by browsers and IIS? This way you don't have to do anything in your application.

Comment: I could use this if I were to host the WCF service within IIS but was hoping to keep a windows service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't use the built in IIS GZip capabilities then you can always do it manually e.g.

```
public static byte[] Compress(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(zip, list);
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    } 
}
```

Then just have your WCF method return a byte array which you can then decompress & deserialize on the client side.

The above code is an extension method so you can basically just call `return myList.Compress()`.